# VB.net check for quantity availability with mysql database

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone help me about monitoring the quantity of items inside my database? The flow is like this if there is no item quantity inside the database there will be a prompt that there is no available item.

Comment: What are your efforts so far ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

`Dim count As Integer = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count()`

Wherein `ds` is declared as `DataSet` and you referenced your database object here.